# TYPO3 error with extension "extension_builder" ExtensionValidator does not exist. Reflection failed

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Following [this](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/master/en-us/Extbase/FirstExtbaseExtension.html) TYPO3 tutorial to create a extension, I installed the extension extension_builder with composer. (My TYPO3 installation is also based on composer).

That worked perfect, but when I reloaded the page and navigated to "Extension Builder", I got this error:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know if that's the best solution, but that worked for me:

I inserted the following lines at the end of my general composer.json (in the root directory)

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["public/typo3conf/ext/extension_builder/Classes/Domain/Validator/ExtensionValidator.php", "public/typo3conf/ext/extension_builder/Classes/Service/ParserService.php"]
}
```